# Large object in Silverlight / ASP.NET / WCF project?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, session-variables

I have to deal with a class that takes about 2-3 minutes to load.  This object is on the server side of a silverlight / ASP / WCF project. Once loaded, this object will contain a list of 5 000 000 smaller object that will be used to perform some calculation.

Users doesn't mind waiting 2 or 3 minutes when the application is loading but they don't want to wait again each time they calculate something.

I would like your input about my options.

Option A: Keep the large object in a session variable.  Some people claims that session variable are poison... especially when used with large object.  Is it really that bad?

Option B: Load the large object when the server start, then find a way to shared or duplicate this object between sessions

Option C (This one would work... but it's not perfect): Create a second object that will copy the 5 000 000 object from my time consuming class then send it to the client side.  However, this solution is not perfect because those 5 000 000 objects are sensible data that should not be accessible "as is" on the client side.

Comment: Can you provide any clues as to why it makes sense to copy 5,000,000 objects to the client? Can't you perform the calculation on the server, where the data already exist?

Comment: Performing the calculation on the server side is what I would like to do... that's why I would rather use the Option A or B.  Option C is more like a workaround.

Comment: the data you sent on server can be encrypted.. but if you store data in cookies you need to serialize your object as well... and cookies has limited space..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you give out three methods, the first and second method ,use the seesion , i think  they are not the good ideas.

i suggest, if you have the big memory ,you can change the class to static class. because the static class not instance it.

or 
you can use the cache to cache the instance.

Comment: I really like the static class solution!  And that doesn't involve a lot of changes to my class (change it to static / make it thread safe)